# XML as messagee content in JSON format

Tags: xml, json

I am sending data to the browser using JSON format. But when data is a XML, I am getting parser error in the browser. How should I send xml content as data in JSON?

Comment: Please post examples: what do you send, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you need to pass the xml as a string, escaping any quotes by putting a '\' just before them.